# Error: Variable declaration not allowed here

Tags: java

I get this error and I don't know what to do, please can some one tell me a good answer.

```
import java.util.*;
public class test{
    public static int expand(int[] a,int n){
        if (n==1)
            return a;
        if (n<=0)
            return new int[0];
        if(n<1)
            int []c=new int[a.length*n];
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                int num=a[i]/n;
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    c[i*n+j]=num;
                }
            }
            return  c;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the n number:");
        int x=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("please enter the size of array:");
        int arr=sc.nextInt();
        int []b=new int [arr];
        for(int o=0;o<b.legnth;o++){
            System.out.println("please enter the"+o+"number:");
            b[o]=sc.nextInt();

        }
        System.out.println("Java tester"+b);
        System.out.println("expanded form is"+expand(b,x));
    }
}
```

**I get this error:**

> variable declaration not allowed here

why though?
i dont think I can remove identifying it as an `integer` or else it wont work

Comment: Add braces to your if-tests in `expand`. Without braces, only the next line will be inside the if-block.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I suspect you mean `n>1` rather than `n<1` too, because there are no values of `n` which would match that condition. Or, just remove the `if` entirely, because it then handles all other n values.

Comment: Always use curly braces for an if then, for, while,...

Comment: And hint: improve your naming. There is no point in using single characters for everything. names are for your human readers. They communicate intent. Your names ... not so much ...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are trying to declare an object in an `if else` scope but no are using curly braces `{ }`

Change the code to:

```
if (n < 1) {
  int[] c = new int[a.length * n];
}
```

Or declare `int []c = new int [a.length]` at the top of the function and assing without declaration

```
c = new int[a.length*n];
```

Comment: Yes, now we have code which compiles, but still makes no sense because since `c` can't be accessed from anywhere else (which compiler was trying to warn as about in previous version).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted to achieve:

```
public static int[] expand(int[] a,int n) {
    if (n==1)
        return a;
    if (n<=0)
        return new int[0];
    int []c =new int[0];
    if(n<1) {
        c = new int[a.length * n];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int num = a[i] / n;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                c[i * n + j] = num;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

errors in your code were related to incorrect return type(int instead of int[]), c out of scope in for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] expand(int[] a,int n){
    int [] c = null;
    if (n==1)
        return a;
    if (n<=0)
        return new int[0];
    if(n<1){
        c = new int[a.length*n];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            int num=a[i]/n;
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                c[i*n+j]=num;
            }
        }
    }
    return  c;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! :) Answers with just a code-snippet are usually frowned upon. Please always give a short summary of what you've modified in the code, and why.